# Can't run the .apk that generated by Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I have built an android app using `expo build:android` for a react native project. And then I can't ran the .apk on my 2 android phones. Error message `App not installed` was shown after ran the .apk on my phones.

I tried to rollback to older versions of my code and I found that the .apk can ran after I used the old `slug` value in `app.json`

I installed the .apk at android emulator. Error message `The APK failed to install. Error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Package /data/app/vmdl1022936792.tmp/base.apk has no certificates at entry AndroidManifest.xml` is shown.

Having no ideas why this happens. How I can use a new `slug` value and build a valid .apk via Expo?

Answer (score 1):

I feel code signing is the problem, the app is not able to install on another android only for this reason. 
Use this link 
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/distribution/app-signing/

try using command

```
   expo build:android --clear-credentials
```